# how to add double variable value with percentage(%)?

Tags: javascript

I want to add 10% of value due to effect from nature to my pokemon.

example: adamant nature give pokemon 10% more attack and reduce 10% sp.atk.
bashfull nature give nothing, and bold let pokemon got 10% on def and reduce attack value.

I tried several times but didn't found a solution.
Btw if my code has something unnecessary please tell me

```js
const pokemon_nature = [
    'Adamant',
    'Bashfull',
    'Bold',
]

function all_random_stats() {
    var level_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 2;
    console.log('level\t= ' , level_value);

    var nature_value = pokemon_nature[(Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon_nature.length))];
    console.log('Nature = ', nature_value);

    var attack_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1 ;
    console.log('attack\t=',attack_value);

    var defence_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1 ;
    console.log('defence\t=',defence_value);

    var sp_attack_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1 ;
    console.log('sp.attack\t=',sp_attack_value);
    
    var pokemon_random_stats = level_value , attack_value, defence_value, sp_attack_value;

    return pokemon_random_stats;
}

all_random_stats()
```

Comment: At first this has less to do with code and more to do with making it a formula. Can you write it just as a math formula? Why is `all_random_stats()` returning a single value? Try `console.log(all_random_stats());` at the end. You can make this script run in StackOverflow with the `<>` button.

Comment: Adding 10% is like multiplying by 1.1 and removing 10% is like multiplying by 0.9. `100 * 1.1 = 110` and `100 * 0.9 = 90.`

Comment: thanks for answering my question. i think i almost got it . but can i do raise and reduce both variable in one sentence? 
ex: pokemon have bold (reduce atk 10%& raise def value 10%) nature and his current atk is 100 and def 50. can u show me how to edit both var value? i'm a newbie

Comment: If you really want it on one line you could do `[pokemon.atk, pokemon.def] = [pokemon.atk * 1.1, pokemon.def * 0.9]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch case to make effect to your pokemon according to the pokemon nature. Then if you want to insert all of your stats into a variable, you have to use array or object. For the example I use object :

```js
const pokemon_nature = [
    'Adamant',
    'Bashfull',
    'Bold',
]

function all_random_stats() {
    // generate random values
    var level_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 2;
    var nature_value = pokemon_nature[(Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon_nature.length))];
    var attack_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1 ;
    var defence_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1 ;
    var sp_attack_value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 31) + 1 ;
    
    // add effect according to pokemon nature
    switch(nature_value) {
        case "Adamant": attack_value *= 1.1; sp_attack_value *= 0.9
        case "Bold": attack_value *= 0.9; defence_value *= 1.1
    }

    // insert all stats into an object
    var pokemon_random_stats = {
        "level_value": level_value, 
        "attack_value": attack_value, 
        "defence_value": defence_value, 
        "sp_attack_value": sp_attack_value
    };

    return pokemon_random_stats;
}

// don't forget to print the result
console.log(all_random_stats())
```